# TFS 2015 - Cannot accept or decline a code review response

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc, tfs-code-review

I am not able to close a code review request. there isn't button (or link) to accept or decline the request.

I checked the security of the user and everything seems fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is bogus. you are the requestor and the reviewer. So, you get only controls for requestor. There is your link - "close review". And in drop down probably "abandon review"

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, we can see that your requester and reviewer are the same person: `George Lati`. When you act as both requester and reviewer, you do not have the option of `accept or decline` at this time. Below is my reproduce:

[image]

When you add other reviewers, other reviews have the option of `accept or decline`.

[image]

[image]

So this is normal behavior.

Comment: I've read your answer after my comment and this is a match. OP could at least accept the answer you gave